# Library not found for -lFirebaseCore in react native IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, react-native

I am facing the same issue with my React Native IOS app, I am already launching the project on clicking "PROJECT-NAME".xcworkspace .  Also I have make sure to Build Active Architecture Only

[image]

Using -

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.63.3
xcode: 12.5.1

Answer (score 0):

changing build system to new build system solve this issue for me